# TeXstudio fails to compile a Nature template

Tags: errors, compiling, texstudio, texmaker, compilation-error

I have downloaded a template for Nature article from Sharelatex (from [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/journals/nature)), but when I try to compile it using TeXstudio or TexMaker it gives me this error message:

```
File `nature.cls' not found. ^^M
```

In the overleaf site the same template compiles... someone knows what could be the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the nature package. Best way to use the package manager of miktex or texlive (whatever distro you use) or worst case download it from https://ctan.org/pkg/nature, unzip and place the files in the same folder as your tex document

Comment: @Ohm texlive was already installed, otherwise you would not have gotten the `File nature.cls not found. ^^M` error. Now you possibly have multiple versions of texlive (linux comes already with one). Check which one is used by texmaker (maybe you can see some path in the texmaker options) and install the nature package for this texlive

Comment: @Ohm Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu helps in disentangling the different versions. I recommend to NOT use the linux version, but install vanilla texlive. The linux versions are often very outdated